# Join master and detail tables as one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a master table and detail table like below

**Master Table**

```
Id    code   Name
-------------------
1     00     qqq
```

**Detail Table**

```
Id    code   Name
-------------------
1     01     xyz
1     02     pqr
1     03     abc
1     04     aaa
```

now I need the result like below

**Result**

```
Id    code  Name
-----------------
1     00    qqq
1     01    xyz
1     02    pqr
1     03    abc
1     04    aaa
```

***I like to avoid UNION***

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Any reason why you want to avoid `union`?

Comment: Yes, because its a complex query. I have to query the data with the combination of other parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know why you don't want to use Union.

But you can use [**FULL OUTER JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) for that, if u don't want to use union. something like this -

```
SELECT COALESCE(Master1.id, Detail.id) AS id
    ,COALESCE(Master1.code, Detail.code) AS code
    ,COALESCE(Master1.NAME, Detail.NAME) AS NAME
FROM MASTER1
FULL OUTER JOIN DETAIL ON Master1.code = Detail.code
```

### Output

```
Id    code  Name
-----------------
1     00    qqq
1     01    xyz
1     02    pqr
1     03    abc
```

Check SQL Fiddle

### [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6abdd/1)

Comment: Why don't use ISNULL instead of COALESCE?

Comment: @CiucaS: Well you can achieve the same result using Isnull.

Comment: I know, but I thought there was a reason why you used COALESCE

Comment: Thanks to all for discussion. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If table is not large enough you can create a temporary table and insert the data from both master and detail by using

insert into temp_table select * from detail;

insert into temp_table select * from master;

or if you want you can also use undermentioned query to combine data of the table

insert into master select * from detail;

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of achieving this... you can try creating a temp table and pushing all the data into it and then select distinct kind of stuff ..

Below is another approach by using CTE, let us know if it works for you

```
CREATE TABLE #Master
( ID INT, Code VARCHAR(50), Name VARCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE #Details 
( ID INT, Code VARCHAR(50), Name  varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #Master values(1,'00', 'qqq')

INSERT INTO #Details values(1,'01', 'xyz')
INSERT INTO #Details values(1,'02', 'pqr')
INSERT INTO #Details values(1,'03', 'abc')
INSERT INTO #Details values(1,'04', 'aaa')


; WITH CTE_RESULT AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE, NAME ORDER BY CODE, NAME) ROW_NO, ID, CODE, NAME 
    FROM #Details D 
)
SELECT A.ID, A.CODE, A.NAME FROM CTE_RESULT A 
INNER JOIN #Master M ON M.ID=A.ID WHERE ROW_NO=1
```